# Regex Nested Quantifier exception while matching regular expression.

Tags: c#, regex

```
int characterLimit = 5;
Regex regxForAlpha = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z \n] {0,"+characterLimit.ToString()+"}+$");
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewTextValue))
if (!Regex.IsMatch( e.NewTextValue, regxForAlpha)){
}
else
{
}
```

This code is throwing NestedQuantifier exception. Can any one know why?

Comment: It is the "+" after {n,n} . Delete "+" Like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210206/what-is-a-nested-quantifier-and-why-is-it-causing-my-regex-to-fail

Comment: If I remove + its not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fixed code:

```
string NewTextValue = "str";
int characterLimit = 5;
string regxForAlpha = "^[a-zA-Z \n]{0,"+characterLimit.ToString()+"}$";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NewTextValue))
    if (!Regex.IsMatch( NewTextValue, regxForAlpha)){
        Console.WriteLine("No match");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Match");
    }
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Leq3Rw) (changed `e.NewTextValue` to `NewTextValue` for demo purposes).

There are several points of interest:

- `Regex.IsMatch` accepts a *string*, not a Regex object, as its second parameter
- .NET regex does not support *possessive* quantifiers that you were using (at the end of your regex, there was `{0,5}+` - and that `+` caused the nested quantifier issue).
- Also, there must be no space between a pattern and the limiting quantifier that restricts the pattern length. So, when you define the pattern as `[a-zA-Z \n] {0,5}`, the `{0,5}` is *applied to the space* that stands next to it on the left, and the meaning of the regex is somewhat distorted.

Answer (score 0):

Please, change

```
Regex regxForAlpha = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z \n] {0,"+characterLimit.ToString()+"}+$");
```

to

```
Regex regxForAlpha = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z \n] {0,"+characterLimit.ToString()+"}$");
```

Comment: Does it raise the same exception?

Comment: Thanks @Helen Downs, I got solution.