# Regex string not ending a character

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find double values in a string. String like this :

("A1K 90" AK2 90.0000 90.0000d nil nil (QUOTE ("90" "duz" nil nil 4.0)))

I only want 90.0000 and 4.0. Not 90.0000d.

```
My regex is -?[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1,6}+(?![a-zA-Z])
```

This works in notepad++. But in c# it errors nested quantifier +.

This problem {}+. Then I removed +. But now my pattern broken.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Use an atomic group  - `(?>-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1,6}+)(?![a-zA-Z])` (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/210286/3832970)).

Comment: This works but errors in c# again. MatchCollection _collection = Regex.Matches(line, @"(?>-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1,6}+)(?![a-zA-Z])")

Comment: Sorry, the `+` must be removed, forgot to delete it after copy/pasting `(?>-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1,6})(?![a-zA-Z])`. I actually wrote about that in the comment I removed: you need to remove the `+` after the limiting quantifier `{1,6}`.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/SQQvJf

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Now it works in c#.